# Google font not working

Tags: css, fonts

I want to use Lato light google font on my website.

Added link herf=... and font family tag per instruction, but it's not working properly.

On my laptop where I have Lato fonts installed, I see Lato light font implemented; however, on my friend's computer as well as on my phone, I'm not seeing Lato light font (I see some random font instead)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en-us">
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />



body {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
background-color: white;
font-weight: 300;
color: #595959; 
letter-spacing: 1.4px;
```

}

I don't know what the problem is -- when I delete font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; below body {, I no longer see Lato font on my computer....  so it's working, but quite properly.

Input would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: use important like this "font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif !important;"

Comment: I would start by adding a doctype declaration, since without it the page is technically invalid, which makes your render mode somewhat unpredictable.

Comment: its working fine here. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j1ajzo4p/ . I have changed few elements for better understanding.

Comment: it has <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> at the beginning. Is this what you meant? @TiesonT.

Comment: @OmarFaruque that didn't work :/

Comment: Try Answer no 2

Comment: @Karuppiah do you suggest i make any changes? or you mean it should work as it is...

Comment: @user2277916 it should work

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I would suggest amending your question to include an actual snippet of what your real code looks like - what you have is bits and pieces. Also, if you're using an XHTML doctype, your link tag needs to be self-closing (so, it should end with a `/>`, not `>`).

Answer (score 1):

Try to this way, I think this is working very well

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Can you provide the url when you used

Comment: please call head section this line <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: then notify me.

Comment: K just did. Btw I added  "/" at the end. so rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: I didn't see where you call google font in the head section

Comment: Ah. I just figured out what the problem is. So I was editing only a single page from a website.  My friend wrote code and there isn't a single html doc. He wrote html doc for each pages separately, but some pages don't have <head> tag. No doc!type tag. It starts with <div> tag right away. What to do in this case?

Comment: OK I just tried adding the tag and it worked. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: I think that is no matter what about you have used or not you can call any where this line this is working very well <link href="fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,9‌​00"; rel="stylesheet">

Comment: If you don't mind answering, nav bar menu text (i.e. work about contact) is set as Adobe Garamond Pro correctly on my laptop. Again, it's not implemented on mobile though. What could be the issue here? It's not a Google font.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine with right html declarations. And you can use updated lato font link

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #595959; 
    letter-spacing: 1.4px;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">

  <head>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>

  <body>
 
    <p>I am paragraph</p>
  </body>

</html>
```